# Create conda virtual environment (Python 3.9) with openssl 1.1.1

Tags: python, openssl, conda

Is it possible to create conda virtual environment with python 3.9 but old openssl, lets say, 1.1.1 version? By default, I get openssl 3.x version. I need old openssl version to have md4 enabled in hashlib. I already tried to edit my openssl 3.x to include legacy_sect but to no avail.

Comment: Conda depends itself on openssl, so I guess no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try to add something like this specifying `python` and `openssl` version while installing.

```
conda create -n venv python=3.9 openssl=1.1.1
```

Comment: @merv my bad, I did it mistakenly while editing the above text